# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shelter_v11' after docker-compose build

Tags: python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

I am learning and I am following [this article](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/), on win10.

my **Dockerfile** is

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ../requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
```

**my docker-compose.yml is**

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  web:
    build: ./
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    env_file:
      - ./envs/.env
```

proj tree is

```
[shelter_v11]/
├── envs/.env
├── [shelter_v11]/
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── docker-compose.yml
├── requirements.txt
└── manage.py
```

The full err message that I get from the docker is

```
2023-05-01 15:12:02 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 402, in run_from_argv
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.execute(\*args, \*\*cmd_options)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 74, in execute
2023-05-01 15:12:02     super().execute(\*args, \*\*options)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 448, in execute
2023-05-01 15:12:02     output = self.handle(\*args, \*\*options)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 81, in handle
2023-05-01 15:12:02     if not settings.DEBUG and not settings.ALLOWED_HOSTS:
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.\_setup(name)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in \_setup
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.\_wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
2023-05-01 15:12:02     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2023-05-01 15:12:02     return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1030, in \_gcd_import
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1007, in \_find_and_load
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 972, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 228, in \_call_with_frames_removed
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1030, in \_gcd_import
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1007, in \_find_and_load
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 984, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
2023-05-01 15:12:02 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shelter_v11'
2023-05-01 15:12:02
2023-05-01 15:12:02 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2023-05-01 15:12:02
2023-05-01 15:12:02 Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/src/app/manage.py", line 22, in \<module\>
2023-05-01 15:12:02     main()
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/src/app/manage.py", line 18, in main
2023-05-01 15:12:02     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
2023-05-01 15:12:02     utility.execute()
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 440, in execute
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 415, in run_from_argv
2023-05-01 15:12:02     connections.close_all()
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 84, in close_all
2023-05-01 15:12:02     for conn in self.all(initialized_only=True):
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 76, in all
2023-05-01 15:12:02     return \[
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 73, in __iter__
2023-05-01 15:12:02     return iter(self.settings)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 57, in __get__
2023-05-01 15:12:02     res = instance.__dict__\[self.name\] = self.func(instance)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 45, in settings
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.\_settings = self.configure_settings(self.\_settings)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 148, in configure_settings
2023-05-01 15:12:02     databases = super().configure_settings(databases)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/connection.py", line 50, in configure_settings
2023-05-01 15:12:02     settings = getattr(django_settings, self.settings_name)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __getattr__
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.\_setup(name)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in \_setup
2023-05-01 15:12:02     self.\_wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 190, in __init__
2023-05-01 15:12:02     mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2023-05-01 15:12:02     return \_bootstrap.\_gcd_import(name\[level:\], package, level)
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1030, in \_gcd_import
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1007, in \_find_and_load
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 972, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 228, in \_call_with_frames_removed
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1030, in \_gcd_import
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 1007, in \_find_and_load
2023-05-01 15:12:02   File "\<frozen importlib.\_bootstrap\>", line 984, in \_find_and_load_unlocked
2023-05-01 15:12:02 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'shelter_v11'
```

I tried moving envs to app dir, switched in dockerfile to WORKDIR "$APP_HOME", ENV HOME=/home/app ENV APP_HOME=/home/app/web, docker-compose build from project app, from the app, moving the manage.py and requirements in the app, in the proj, tried again. To me it looks like my app is somehow not detected/found. Any help and assistance with info what this error could mean or how to solve is much appreciated.

Comment: Your setup differs from what is stated in the given tutorial. Author has one more top-level folder which contains the whole django project and docker-compose files are in this folder, not inside django. Your `dockerfile` is stored way too deep and not like in the tutorial. `build: ./` is supposed to point to the folder where dockerfile is stored - yours is not. Please read tutorial more carefully and use help for each tool in use.

Comment: Thank you a lot, I have started from scratch, basically re-arranging the project with one extra level solved it yes.